# How to implement if check in column template

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I understand I can have an if condition in the .ClientTemplate, but how can I do this outside of the client template and in the column template? For instance, I have a column action link that when clicked will go to a new form. I want a condition where if true, show the action link icon, else show a non-clickable icon. Example code of one of my columns below

```
columns.Template(
        @<text>
            @Html.ActionLink("New", "CreateFormsIndex", new { Controller = "Forms", id = "#=ProjectId#", revDt = "#=NextReviewDate#" })
        </text>)
             .ClientTemplate("<a href='/ProjectManagers/Forms/CreateFormsIndex?id=#=ProjectId#&revDt=#=NextReviewDate#'><span class=\"fa fa-file-o\"></span></a>")
             .Title("New Review")
             .HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align: center" })
             .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align: center" });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below code snippet.

```
 .ClientTemplate(" # if (YourField) { #" +
                        "<a href='/ProjectManagers/Forms/CreateFormsIndex?id=#=ProjectId#&revDt=#=NextReviewDate#'><span class=\"fa fa-file-o\"></span></a>" +
                        "# } else { #" +
                        "<span class=\"fa fa-file-o\"></span>" +
                        "# } #")
```